# How to improve .NET Core Web API performance?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dnx

I'm trying to create a Web API application which would be able to process 10K+ req/sec.

I created an empty .NET Core Web API project with just one GET action which simply returns a string. I publish my self-containing app to Debian8 server.

```
dotnet publish -r debian.8-x64 -c Release
```

Then I run a load test using Apache Benchmark using following options.

```
ab -n 50000 -c -k 200 localhost:5000/api/cnt/dummy
```

The result of the test is 4.5K req/sec.

Is there any way to increase the performance of my Web API application?

My `project.json` file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression": "1.0.0"

  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true,
      "System.GC.Concurrent": true
    }
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {},
    "debian.8-x64": {}
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

My `Startup.cs` file:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        if (env.IsEnvironment("Development"))
        {
            // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
            builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
        }

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look here https://github.com/aspnet/benchmarks. Comparing the runs of your benchmarks with the provided .NET ones should tell you if it is a problem with your code or your hardware. What are the specs of the machine your running, what is the CPU utilisation?

Comment: Have you tried to use Profiler to understand the application performance yet ? You could just use Visual Studio Profiler to find out what is doing most work, and use that knowledge to improve the performance of your application.

Comment: As a starter, question yourself whether you need MVC or not. Really high throughput is best done directly in the Middleware. Logging and insights costs. Also your counter controller might miscount due to threading.

Answer (score 1):

From our experience `ab` won't let you hit this number. You need another load test tool like https://github.com/wg/wrk. Some others will work too.

You can still try to use multiple ab processes at the same time. Then use a specific number of clients for a specific time. For instance `-c 20 -t 30 -k`.